# Linux : Search and Replace with multiple Special Characters

Tags: linux, search, sed, replace, command-line

I want to searchNreplace following in all directories and in all files(.php)

```
 < $abc("A","ABC"); > To < $abc("O","OPQ"); >
```

I tried

```
 find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/\$abc(\"A\",\"ABC\")\;/\$abc(\"O\",\"OPQ\")\;/g' {} \;

 find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/@$abc("A","ABC");/@$abc("O","OPQ");/g' {} \;
```

with no success

Comment: not sure why you added `@` in second sed version... there are no special characters that need escaping here.. both should work.. you'll have to add more details on `no success`... or create testable sample that we can check...

Comment: @Sundeep, there is no error in o/p. however, there is no change in the files as well. thats why I'm stuck.

Comment: then try with a sample file to narrow down the issue.. for ex: `echo '$abc("A","ABC");' | sed 's/$abc("A","ABC");/$abc("O","OPQ");/g'` .. then next step would be to put that sample in a file and check.. after that, check with single file in a directory plus find.. and so on

Comment: Could you provide some sample input data? Your regex/replacement seems to match fine when I have `$abc("A","ABC");` in various places over the file. I suspect there might be something like a white space after the comma that was not accounted for? Perhaps something like `'s/\(\$abc(\)"A"\(,\s*\)"ABC");/\1"O"\2"OPQ");/g'`.  Also node `"` and `;` should not need to be escaped, removing that makes the regex a bit easier to read.